# PERL CGI CLI Special Characters Question Mark

Tags: perl

When I use Question Mark character (?) in a CLI parameter it doesn't populate the value (using http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI/lib/CGI.pm#DEBUGGING). Even if it is escaped.

This will not populate "param" at all:

perl httpPost.pl param="http://www.test.com/?user=test"

perl httpPost.pl param="http://www.test.com/\?user=test"

This will return the characters until ?

Comment: Do you want to pass your script the parameter `param` that contains an URL with a parameter `user`, or do you want to pass your script the parameter `user` and have it believe that it was called under the URL `http://www.test.com/`? Have you tried proper URL-encoding for the parameter value (e.g. `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2F%3Fuser%3Dtest`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to URL encode your parameters so characters that are special to URLs will be converted into %XX strings. Those character strings will be decoded on the other side.

There are a number of modules on the CPAN that will help you with url-encoding. here are a few:

1. [URL::Encode](https://metacpan.org/module/URL%3a%3aEncode)
2. [URI::URL](https://metacpan.org/module/URI%3a%3aURL)

and in a broader sense: [Search MetaCPAN for url_encode](https://metacpan.org/search?q=url_encode)

Comment: Thanks. That works!

Ideally all input should be encoded.

This site provides a web interface to encode URL string.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/